Decimal point does not follow locale in Docasssemble
I'd like to enter numeric values in a question of a Docassemble interview with German format ("," as decimal point). The YML part looks like this:
---
question: |
  Übersetzung
fields:
  - Übersetzung: specimen_assembly_translated
    input type: area
    default: |
      ${ specimen_assembly_translated }
  - Variable ohne Sinn: no_sense_var
    datatype: number
  - Variable ohne Sinn 2: no_sense_var2
    datatype: number
---

What I expect: After I typed in a fractional number in the field (e.g. "13,8"), I click "Continue" and the number is saved to the interview.
What I get: After I typed in a fractional number in the field (e.g. "13,8") and switched to another field, the "," disappeared. When I type in "13.8" everything is fine.
I installed Docassemble 1.6.0 as single Docker container. When I enter the container console, more /etc/default/locale returns LANG=de_DE.UTF-8. Other configuration inside Docassemble:
country: DE
language: de
locale: de_DE
os locale: de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8
other os locales:
  - de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8
timezone: Europe/Berlin

When I get the documentation right, what decimal point will be chosen depends on the locale setting. I tried with different browsers; same result. I guess that I'm missing something with the locale setting. The Docke ENV LOCALE is also de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8. Where am I wrong?
